# How to prevent Users to use ad blocker on my website?

Tags: javascript, php, popup-blocker

Hey any one know how to prevent users to use ad blocker on my site.I just want to request them not to use it on my site..

Comment: The traditional approach is to place an image behind (`z-index`) ad spots that say "Please don't block our ads".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a Javascript file called `advertisement.js` with this code:

```
var noadblock = true;
```

Include it on your page somewhere:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="advertisement.js"></script>
```

The idea is that adblock will block the file called `advertisement.js` and your var will never be created. So you can use this to take action based on whether the var exists or not:

```
window.onload = funtion(){
    if (noadblock){
        // no adblock
    }else{
        // adblock detected, do stuff here
    }
}
```

Updated cus somone in the comments had a better idea.

Comment: Why not just set a variable in advertisement.js? For example, `adsNotBlocked = true;`. Then just check `if (!adsNotBlocked)`

Comment: good point +1 @DavidSherret

Comment: Heh I like this option.

Comment: @Adelphia please create a java script for me.m new to website and i know enough about these thing m learning though.please creat a file and send to me at supershaheens@gmail.com .i shall be very thankful to you.

Comment: @HassanMunir Firstly, no. SO isn't a place to get free coding done. My Instructions were pretty straight forward. Open notepad, paste in the single line of code I posted and save  it as "advertisement.js". Secondly, now that your question has been answered please mark the check mark to select it.

Comment: @Adelphia here is my second question i hope you can help me thanks.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26377527/how-to-add-categoryposts-in-wordpress-single-post

Comment: Thank you @HassanMunir, unfortunately I don't use wordpress but it looks like you've got some good advice on that question. Best of luck.